# Inequality for XOR

Tags: inequality

I was reading a book of neural networks in Spanish and I do not understand the inequalities on page 26

the book:
http://disi.unal.edu.co/~lctorress/RedNeu/LiRna004.pdf

I have a table of XOR and inequality restrictions

[image]

[image]
then:

[image]

if there are no contradictions in the previous inequalities, the problem is linearly separable, as observed from the inequalities 2, 3, 4 is impossible

[image]

and that its sum is less than zero

**my question is how that result of contradiction(inequalities 2,3,4)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let rewrite the inequalities:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 * W_{1,1} + 0 * W_{2,1} + b &< 0 \tag{$p_1$} \\
0 * W_{1,1} + 1 * W_{2,1} + b &\geq 0 \tag{$p_2$} \\
1 * W_{1,1} + 0 * W_{2,1} + b &\geq 0 \tag{$p_3$}\\
1 * W_{1,1} + 1 * W_{2,1} + b &< 0 \tag{$p_4$} \\
\end{align*}
$$

From ($p_1$), we have $b<0$. From ($p_2$) and ($p_3$), we have $W_{1,1}+b\geq 0$ and $W_{2,1}+b\geq0$ so that $W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+2b\geq 0$. However, ($p_4$) implies a contradiction $W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+b<0$, because (as $b<0$)
$$
W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+b \geq W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+2b \geq 0
$$

Comment: then the contradiction is W1,1+W2,1+b<=0    and     W1,1+W2,1+2b≥0

Comment: please 
you could explain a little more the last part

Comment: @x-rw At first ($p_1$) says $b$ is negative. So $b\geq 2b$. OK? Now add ($p_2$) and ($p_3$), then you have $W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+2b\geq0$. However $b\geq 2b$ so that $W_{1,1}+W_{2,1}+b\geq 0$ too. But it contradict to ($p_4$).

Comment: how to come to the conclusion of b>=2b

Comment: @x-rw From ($p_1$) we know $b$ is negative. So $b\geq 2b$. For example, $-1>-2$.

Comment: a last question please, how to come to the conclusion is imposible of W2,1>=0 and W1,1>=0?

Comment: @x-rw ($p_2$) implies $W_{2,1}\geq0$ and ($p_3$) implies $W_{1,1}\geq0$. But ($p_4$) does not say that its sum is negative. Instead its sum plus $b$ is negative. You may miss something in translating the book, or the author of the book may miss something. Anyway the problem is not linearly separable because there is a contradition.